# What are the parameters in this overload of AddImage in the IText PDF library?

Tags: itext

Sorry if this question is too specific to a particular library, however it seems popular enough that somebody might know the answer to this. The API documentation for AddImage does not say what each of the arguments are:

```
public PdfXObject addImage(ImageData image,
                       float a,
                       float b,
                       float c,
                       float d,
                       float e,
                       float f)
Creates Image XObject from image and adds it to canvas (as Image XObject).
Parameters:
image - the PdfImageXObject object
a - an element of the transformation matrix
b - an element of the transformation matrix
c - an element of the transformation matrix
d - an element of the transformation matrix
e - an element of the transformation matrix
f - an element of the transformation matrix
```

Obviously two are x/y coords, and presumably 2 are height and width, but from the "legacy" code I'm working with, it's not apparent which is which, and I can't think what the other two floats could be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those six values are elements of a matrix that has three rows and three columns:

[image]

You can use this matrix to express a transformation in a two-dimentional system.
Carrying out this multiplication results in this:

[image]

Carrying out this multiplication results in this:

```
x' = a * x + c * y + e
y' = b * x + d * y + f
```

The third column in the matrix is fixed: you’re working in two dimensions, so you don’t need to calculate a new z coordinate.

When studying analytical geometry in high school, you’ve probably learned how to apply transformations to objects. In PDF, we use a slightly different approach: instead of transforming objects, we transform the coordinate system.

Nevertheless, you can use your high school knowledge of analytical geometry to understand what the different values are about. For instance:

- `e` and `f` are the values you will need for the *translation* of the object, so if you want to add the image at the position `x = 36; y = 36`, then you will need `e = 36; f = 36`.
- `a` and `d` are the values you will need for the *scaling* in case you don't have any *rotation*. For instance: if you want the image to have a width of 100 user units and a height of 50 user units, you will need `a = 100; b = 0; c = 0; d = 50`.

So to add an image of 100 by 50 user units of which the lower-left corner coincides with the coordinate `(36, 36)`, you'd need:

```
cb.addImage(img, 100, 0, 0, 50, 36, 36);
```

You can use the following formulas to compute the values for `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f`. For example, if you want to combine a translation `(dX, dY)`, a scaling `(sX, sY)`, and a rotation `ϕ`:

```
a = sX * cos(ϕ);
b = sY * sin(ϕ);
c = sX * -sin(ϕ);
d = sY * cos(ϕ);
e = dX;
f = dY;
```

These are all things you can rediscover if you dig into your high school books. It's simple Math; the stuff I learned at school at the age of 17 ;-)

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that a PDF library would think in these terms, but I understand it now. Not sure why the original maintainer of this thing picked this particular overload, and then didn't see fit to comment it... But all's well that ends well

Comment: Developers should write better documentation. That goes for the original maintainer as well as for the person who wrote the iText Javadocs ;-)

Comment: Anybody willing to go near PDF probably earns at least one or two free passes